# What's a good image size target for a store's products?

Tags: e-commerce, image-format

My girlfriend has just asked me what size she should make her product images for her web store, both in terms of dimensions and fill size.

She's very keen to have the images look great when you zoom and fill the screen as much as possible, so my rough estimate was no more than 200kb for the fill size, and for the dimensions no more than 1200px wide for landscape photos, and 1000px high for portrait photos.

What is generally good practise for file sizes? It's hard to find the balance between having a good quality image, but one that also doesn't take too long to download.

Comment: FWIW, bigger is better in that you can always easily downsize. Harder to upsize.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you haven't posted the most important of all the information: what kind of products does she sell? I assume it's a fashion webstore - correct me if I'm wrong - thus I advise you not to worry about ther disk size too much. Size of a particular photo depends on the product, however, among the popular clothes web stores, product pictures oftenly reach enourmous sizes, strongly exceeding diemensions and disk space you have mentioned. Generally, people buying clothes online want to see as much detail as possible (eg fabric, pattern, etc), that's why posting extremely zoomed in and big photos (e.g. Zara online store) is a common practise in this matter. This also depends on type of clothes she sells (if she actually sells clothes as I assumed :)) - if I were to limit the bandwitch, I'd do it more likely if I were selling sneakers rather than Zegna moccasins.

Generally, I think 200KB per picture is a good limit, however exceeding it in cases you think you need to give very detailed picture of the product is not a problem at all, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, it is for a fashion site so I guess like you said maybe the file size isn't as important as being able to clearly see the detail and the fabric, 200kb is probably a nice aim, but if it runs over that I guess it shouldn't hurt too much. Thanks again